# Magento 2 product import won't import images

Tags: magento2

I am importing products using the built in CSV import (System - import - products)

All my data is imported fine, but I get an error
`Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

In my css I have written the base_image path as `://mywebsite.ca/pub/media/import/img/hose/jpg/Ach7938.jpg`

as a test I removed my folder structure, edited the csv and tried this and got same problem, same error `http://mywebsite.ca/pub/media/import/Ach7938.jpg`

I tried writing file path as `/pub/media/import/img/hose/jpg/Ach7938.jpg`
but it won't let me past the "check data" validator.

I confirmed the permissions on the folders and files is 775

I am using PHP 5.6, I tried 7 but it broke the whole site in many different ways, so that isn't an option

As a side note, if I run this 20 times in a row, the entire site hangs and import won't work again until I do a full system restore (whats up with that?)

Can I put the images on a different server and link to them that way?

Answer (score 0):

The Images File Directory needs to be set relative to the Magento `doc root`.

For example if your product images are in `pub/media/catalog/product`

Set that as your Images File Directory.

Comment: I put the images in ```<magento-root>/pub/media/import/``` and I leave the "Images file directory" field empty. I use Magento 2.1.9 (was the same with 2.1.8)

Answer (score 0):

Image path can be relative path or simple name. I've imported with both and it worked. In my case issue was the images given in path wasn't available in folder. I tried it with importing available and not-available image and was getting error in case when that image wasn't available.
Path can be any one ,it isn't must to use `pub/media/import` only.

Answer (score 0):

For the import images issue i have fixed the issue from `Uploader.php` file. change below file path code and success working import images.

File path:
`magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Uploader.php`

Find the below line from line number 201:

`$filePath = $this->_directory->getRelativePath($filePath . $fileName);`

Replace with:

```
$filePath = strpos($filePath, $fileName) !== false ?
$filePath:$this->_directory->getRelativePath($filePath . $fileName);
```

For More information refer to this GitHub link:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/20761/commits/8612789375b0c173f0ba852c587882af6ff8bc7f